# Docker flag "--gpu" does not work without sudo command

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, gpu

I'm ubuntu user. I use the following docker image, `tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu`

If I try to run this command

```
$ docker run -it --rm --gpus all tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-gpu bash
```

There's permission denied error.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: Running hook #0:: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: mount error: open failed: /sys/fs/cgroup/devices/user.slice/devices.allow: permission denied: unknown.
```

Of course, I can run this command if I am using `sudo`, but I want to use `gpu` without `sudo`.

Is there any good solution? Any leads, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your problem seems to be only when running "--gpu".

Add/update these two sections of /etc/nvidia-container-runtime/config.toml

```
[nvidia-container-cli]
no-cgroups = true

[nvidia-container-runtime]
debug = "/tmp/nvidia-container-runtime.log"
```

Source: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/3659#issuecomment-543912380

## If you can't use docker without sudo at all

If you are running in a Linux environment, you need to create a user for docker so you won't need to use `sudo` every time. Below are the steps to create:

```
$ sudo groupadd docker

$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

$ newgrp docker
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/